# How to force quit the "Force Quit Applications" window

Tags: macos, mac, window-manager, force-quit

The "Force Quit Applications" window opened spontaneously due to memory pressure.

Now I can't close the "Force Quit Applications" window itself . The "X" button doesn't close the window and it doesn't have an icon in the dock or a menu bar.

[image]

Comment: Does the `⌘CMD`+`W` work?

Comment: add an answer to get points

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can close it with <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>.

There's a list of the official keyboard shortcuts on [apple.com](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236)

Comment: Doesn't work...

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> was not working for me either.

I had luck by opening the "normal" Force Quit window from *Apple menu * > *Force Quit…*, which replaced the out-of-memory Force Quit window. I was then able to close it normally with the X button.

Answer (score 0):

cmd + w didn't work at first step.

Than I force closed all "paused" applications one by one, after that cmd + w worked.